# SPFx client side web parts onpremise

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am trying to develop a traditional web part (SP2013, SP2010..) to host a modern SPFx client web part. I developed most of the plumbing and wrapping and I have some problems when actually render the client side web part on the screen.

First question: does anyone tried something like that before? Any help / hint could be given? (the reason to develop this is to make the on premise / old environments ready for migration to O365, so the solution could be develop in the latest and greatest)

Second question: Does anyone know the internals of the sp-client-base.js script? I am trying to load all necessary script for the client web part to load, but I have the following exception here:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SPFlight' of undefined

```
 var H = r(21);
 t.SPFlight = H.SPFlight,
 t.UrlQueryParameterCollection = H.UrlQueryParameterCollection,
```

I am trying to load the scripts required by the bundled version of the client side web part:

```
requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: '',
        paths: {
            'react': "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.min",
            "react-dom": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.min",
            "react-dom/server": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom-server.min",
            "office-ui-fabric-react": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/office-ui-fabric-react.bundle_be96abb3871d2a34ee7217886924e19f",
            "@microsoft/sp-client-base": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-client-base_en-us_f35aa94ac66731c2577eee095f5caab4",
            "@microsoft/sp-client-preview": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-client-preview_en-us_361e44159463b3ee4ff7d3885e251a7c",
            "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-lodash-subset_b6842d77d21ead50d00dd0c4c07ec4cd",
            "@microsoft/sp-module-loader": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-module-loader_en-us_5a1887d81f61e6a8129e305758514174",
            "@ms/odsp-utilities-bundle": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/odsp-utilities-bundle_ea5488cbbc2fb35df6547b3ed19bdcd6",
            "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2016-11-21.008/sp-webpart-base_en-us_7d0afa6ccf73b6579e56d7cc6f3990b8"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider following interesting webcast from PnP team:
[Using modern web stack with SharePoint on-premises deployments](https://dev.office.com/blogs/using-modern-web-stack-with-sharepoint-on-premises-deployments)

They are also created project on github demonstrating approach:
[react-generic-app](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/tree/dev/Samples/react-generic-app)

With this approach you can later more smoothly move to SPFx.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I already used this to create full web stack solutions on premise (in react and angular), but I would like to integrate the SPFx ones. So, the same code base  to work on both. Just to upload the spfx package file, copy the bundles somewhere and done. I am trying now to reverse engineer the workbench to try to implement it.

Comment: Now I see... That's really interesting and cool. If you will be able to do this, please ping me :)

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, SPFX is only available in O365.  The plan is to port it to on-prem after it hits General Availability in the service and we have time to iron out any issues that crop up.